# how to create a bar chart with a dual axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

Consider this simple example

```
library(lubridate)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- tibble(time = c(ymd('2019-01-01'),
                        ymd('2019-01-02'),
                        ymd('2019-01-03'),
                        ymd('2019-01-04'),
                        ymd('2019-01-05')),
       var1 = c(2,2,2,2,1),
       var2 = c(2,1,1,4,5),
       var3 = c(200, 200, 400, 500, 230))
```

Now this works

```
p1 <- mydf %>% 
  barchart(var1 + var2 ~ time, 
           data = ., 
           stack = TRUE,
           horiz = FALSE,
           par.settings = simpleTheme(col = c('red', 'blue'),
                                      fill = c('red', 'blue'),
                                      alpha = c(0.2)),
           auto.key = TRUE)
```

[image]

and this works as well

```
p2 <- mydf %>% 
  xyplot(var3 ~ time, data = ., type = 'l')
```

[image]

However, combining them with `latticeExtra::doubleYscale()` does not work. The line is invisible (see below)

```
latticeExtra::doubleYScale(p1, p2, use.style = FALSE)
```

Strangely enough, the dual y scale is there, but the line is missing. Any ideas?

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: mate, you gotta stop using lattice, JK.

Comment: :D lattice is great buddy. ggplot is good but has some insane limitations (dual axes)

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. If I remove `horiz = FALSE` I can get two plots to show (almost) however, the barchart will be distorted. Jokes aside, it seems to me that `lattice` is not maintained very well and I have experienced variety of bugs with it. I am with you on dual axis limitation of ggplot tho, it is annoying. You can get around it using some hacky methods (posted on SO). I personally would go for that hacky solution once in a while, rather than dealing with bugs always. Cheers.

Comment: On the reason for the limitations please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales/3101876#3101876

Comment: ah please stop with these BS ggplot arguments. every field on earth uses double Y axes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your data a bit.

Using `as.layer` (also from `latticeExtra`) rather than `doubleYScale`:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)      

  mydf <- data.frame(t=1:5,x=c(2,2,2,2,1),
             y=c(2,1,1,4,5),z=c(200,200,400,500,230))

    p1 <- barchart(x+y~t,mydf,stack=TRUE,horiz=FALSE,
       par.settings = simpleTheme(col = c('red', 'blue'),
                                           fill = c('red', 'blue'),
                                           alpha = c(0.2)),
                auto.key = TRUE)

    p2 <- xyplot(z~t,mydf,type="l")

    p1+as.layer(p2,x.same=TRUE,y.same=FALSE,outside=TRUE)
```

I trust it also works with lubridated objects and tibbles.

EDIT: to clarify `as.layer` is also in `latticeExtra` package and add the plot.

[image: bar chart plus xyplot]

Comment: cool stuff! can you show the chart here? for future reference

Comment: Done. No need to stop using lattice.

Comment: Well, I see the line. It is faint because of the alpha=0.2. Try `p2 <- xyplot(z~t,mydf,type="l",col="black",alpha=1,lwd=2)`

Comment: If you couldn't see the line, maybe it is your monitor or some such thing. If you increase `alpha`, maybe `doubleYScale` would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using ggplot2, you could do:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- mydf %>% 
  select(-var3) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(var1, var2), 
    names_to = "type",
    values_to = "value"
  )

df2 <- mydf %>% 
  select(time, var3)

ggplot(df1) +
  geom_col(aes(x = time, y = value, fill = type)) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = time, y = var3/100), size = 2) +
  ylab("var1, var2") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*100, name = "var3"))
```

[image: Plot using ggplot2, with two y-axis]